# How to force Invoke-RestMethod to use IPv6 Interface?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to force Invoke-RestMethod to request URI via the IPv6 interface instead of IPv4 on Dual Stacked Windows?

Comment: Via URL?  Yes.  Via command-line arguments?  I don't think so.  However, modern security best practices typically require HTTPS TLS connections to remote REST API endpoints.  So, unless the certificate bound on the remote secure endpoint permits IPSec and defines an IPv6 address(es), I doubt the connection would be classified as truly secure.  Same applies to IPv4 URLs.

Comment: I were trying to write an DDNS Update script. The host side REST API doesnt supply separate IPv4 / IPv6 URLs, so I need to handle this from my end.